# How in python's module CONFIGPARSER read text from variable, not from a file?

Tags: python, ftp, readfile, ini, configparser

The problem is that `config.read("filename.ini")` - requires a local file. I download the content of this file straight into the variable from my FTP server with the help of StringIO.

```
content = StringIO()
f.retrbinary('RETR /folder1/inifile.ini, content.write)
request = content.getvalue()
config.read(request)
```

Comment: [`ConfigParser.read_string(string, source='<string>')`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/configparser.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the python docs.

Using your StringIO object it looks like you can use config.readfp(contents).

Answer (score 0):

i was working with this case and find solution like this

```
content = StringIO()
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read_string(content)
```

then you can access config as object.